# UINavigationController hides back button only on second appearance of view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back

I have three view controllers: A login view, a home tableview screen, and a detail tableview screen. These are all part of the same UINavigationController. On the home screen, I want to disable the back button, preventing a user from backing into the login screen. So in the `viewDidLoad()` function I have

```
// Home View
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    ...
}
```

When this view shows up, there is no back arrow but there is the word "Back." This button does nothing, it seems disabled. When I go to the next view (the detail view), the back button is hidden. Even if I add a `hidesBackButton = false` to the `viewDidLoad` of this view, still nothing. However, the swipe to the right on the navigation bar allows going back.

Now that I am back on the home screen, the back button is completely hidden. If I were to then proceed forward again to the detail view, the back button appears as desired.

**Here's the Sequence of Events:**

1. Login Screen. After you log in the home screen is popped on.

[image: First Login Screen]

2. The Home Screen. The back button is there, where it shouldn't.

[image: Back Button appears without arrow]

3. The detail view. This view should have a back button to go back to the home screen. The swipe functionality still works, so you can go back to the home screen by swiping the navigation bar.

[image: Detail Test View. Should have Back button]

4. When you've gone back, the back button is gone! Like it should be.

[image: Back To Home.]

5. Finally, going back (forward) to the detail view, the back button is there as it should be.

[image: Back to Detail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>On the simulator I reset content and settings, and this seemed to fix the issue.</s>

I still have no idea why the bug was happening in the first place.

#### Real solution

[This](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/i-have-major-issues-here-getting-the-back-button-to-hide-the-back-button-itself-does-not-hide-only-the-arrow) solution actually seems to be working for me!

I simply added

```
var HVC = segue.destinationViewController as! HomeViewController
HVC.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

to the `prepareForSegue` method in the ViewController that created the problematic VC.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as described exactly above and the solution for me was to use:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

in

```
override func viewDidAppear { ... }
```

When I had the setHidesBackButton code in viewDidLoad I got that same exact error, but moving it as noted did the trick!